If given $3$ random real numbers between $0-100$, what is the probability that the median is closest in value to $50$?
I am not a mathematician.
Let us say that I am given $3$ real numbers between $0-100$. If I put the three numbers in numerical order, what is that probability the middle number is the closest in value to $50$?
What are the probabilities of the number closest to $50$ being the lowest or highest number?

Are you requiring that the three numbers be distinct?  Regardless of that (though you should clarify it);  I suggest working backwards.  That is, compute the probability that the middle one isn't closest and, to do that, I'd suggest looking at cases (all three $<50$, all three $≥50$, two below one above, and so on)

Are the three numbers distinct? Which way does it count if the numbers are 40,60,90?

@lulu and Thomas Thanks for that. I have changed the Q to effectively avoid duplicates by stipulating real numbers as opposed to integers. Does that work in terms of clarifying the question?

@lulu Will the probability of one above and two below help?

Your revised version also avoids the problem that @ThomasAndrews mentioned.  My approach still makes sense.  To your question:  Yes.  Each case is necessary.

@lulu I think I'm being slow, but how will the two below, one above help, given that the closet could be either the one above or the highest of the two below?

Yes, you have to analyze those cases (while other cases are obvious).

@lulu Yes, having seen Matthew's answer I think I understand.

Monte Carlo with real numbers $x\in(0,1)$ gives $p_{middle} =1/2, p_{left}=p_{right}=1/4$.

The smallest number is closest to $50$ if (a) it’s at least $50$, or (b) it’s less than $50$ (say, $50-x$), but the other two numbers are greater than $50$ and farther away ($\ge 50+x$).
Case (a) happens exactly if all three numbers are at least $50$: probability $1/8$.  Case (b) happens if just one number is less than $50$ (probability $3/8$) and its reflection across $50$ is the smallest of the three (probability $1/3$): so (b) also has probability $3/8 \times 1/3 = 1/8$.  Combined, (a) and (b) have probability $1/4$.
The largest number is closest with the same probability, $1/4$.  So the median is closest with the remaining probability, $1-1/4-1/4=1/2$.
This can be extended to find the probability that the median of any $n$ values is closest to the center of the range.

Thank you for writing that in a way that even I am able to understand.

I assume you mean that the numbers are uniform i.i.d. between $0$ and $100$. We distinguish four cases, and since the cases are distinct, we can add the probabilities.

Case 1: All numbers are below $50$. This has probability of $\frac{1}{8}$, and probability of middle number being closest is $0$.
Case 2: One number is above $50$. This has a probability of $\frac{3}{8}$ (think of it like this, the probability of number 1 being above and the others below is $\frac{1}{8}$, and we can say this also for the second and third number). Given that the numbers are like this, we basically have that one number is uniformly distributed between $50$ and $100$, and the others uniformly between $0$ and $50$. Say $X_1,X_2\leq 50$ and $X_3>50$ Note that, for the smallest two numbers, replacing $X_i$ by $Y_i=50-X_i$ still gives the same distribution, and for the largest one, we can replace it by $Y_3=X_3-50$ to also get a variable between $0$ and $50$. Then the question which of the three $X_i$ was the closest to $50$ is the same as asking which of the $Y_i$ is the smallest. Obviously, the probability of $X_3$ being closest to $50$ must then be $\frac{1}{3}$, since they would all have equal chance of the $Y_i$ being the smallest. Probability of $\min(X_1,X_2)$ being closest is $0$, hence probability of $\max(X_1,X_2)$ being closest in this case is $\frac{2}{3}$. This gives a total contribution of this case of $\frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{4}$.
Case 3: One number is below $50$. This is symmetric to the other case.
Case 4: All above $50$ is also symmetric.

So in total the probability of the middle one being closest is $\frac{1}{2}$. So then also the probability of the largest one or the smallest one being closest is $\frac{1}{4}$ for each.

Thanks for the great answer. Gave the green tick thingie to mjqxxxx just because I found it easier to work through, though to be fair, that could be because you softened it up for me first!
